# django app how to get a string from a function before

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am building a django app in which the user has to write a sentence in a text box. This sentence gets then sent to the server and received by it. After that the user has to click on continue and gets on a another html page. Here the user has to record an audio of a word he sais. The word is then turned into a string and after that sent to the server. Now I would like the function in views.py to find out if the word the user said is in the sentence the user wrote before. But the sentence is only in the first function that receives the sentence after it is sent. I know I could first store the sentence but is there also another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, at least there is two ways first using a `model` to store the value. or a file maybe.
second using some html magic(? I'm not sure of magic). using an `input type="hidden"`.
your first function receives the text, redirects user to another page but with an argument `the text!`, then inside that template store that text in a hidden input and by clicking the button send both voice and hide value text to the new functon.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Only one more question do I have to return the argument(the text) in order to put it on the second html page?

Comment: it depends, if the first function receives the text is rendering a template, so add `text value` to the context data for `render` function. elif the first function id redirecting a new url path. add that data as an args. e.g `return redirect('myapp_name:myview_name', data=data)` but this one is not very good because the `url` path should be like `path('an-address/<str:data>', views.fn, name='myview_name'),` which result in `data` to be appear in the browser address bar. but may-be there is another solution too